# How to call child function from Parent react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

in my parent component I have a dialog, and in Content of the dialog I load the child component

and this is the `Dialog` in **parent** component

```
<Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
>
    <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText >
            <Child id={id} status={status}/>
        </DialogContentText>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleClose} />
        <Button onClick={handleAcceptClose} />
    </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

and in my child component I have `sayhi` method

```
const sayhi = () => {
    alert("sialaaaaaam");
}
```

How can I call the `sayhi` using **`ref`**, I want to use `ref` because I want a minimum render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to forward a ref to the child component, and use the [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook.

Example `Child` component:

```
const Child = React.forwardRef(
  (props, ref) => {
    const innerRef = React.useRef();

    const sayhi = () => alert("sialaaaaaam");

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      sayhi,
    }));

    return (
      {/* Child JSX */}
    );   
  }
);
```

Then in the parent component create and attach a ref to `Child`:

```
const childRef = React.useRef();

...

<Child ref={childRef} id={id} status={status}/>
```

And to call the `sayhi` function:

```
childRef.current.sayhi();
```